# ctypes not loading share library from the standard paths of dlopen

Tags: python, shared-libraries, ctypes, dynamic-linking

I have a compiled `.so` file in linux that links to `openblas` under my `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, and this is confirmed by `ldd`:

```bash
libopenblas.so.0 => /home/username/.local/lib/libopenblas.so.0 (0x000014a262823000)
```

However, when loading this in the anacodna python, this version is not linked and the one in the anaconda lib is used instead.

This is seen by the following error (I use this error message to print out the true openblas file that is linked):

```py
In [1]: import ctypes
   ...: ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('libopenblas.so.0').name
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-40ebc71b2d6c> in <module>
      1 import ctypes
----> 2 ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('libopenblas.so.0').name

/etc/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/ctypes/__init__.py in __getattr__(self, name)
    375         if name.startswith('__') and name.endswith('__'):
    376             raise AttributeError(name)
--> 377         func = self.__getitem__(name)
    378         setattr(self, name, func)
    379         return func

/etc/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/ctypes/__init__.py in __getitem__(self, name_or_ordinal)
    380
    381     def __getitem__(self, name_or_ordinal):
--> 382         func = self._FuncPtr((name_or_ordinal, self))
    383         if not isinstance(name_or_ordinal, int):
    384             func.__name__ = name_or_ordinal

AttributeError: /etc/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload/../../libopenblas.so.0: undefined symbol: name
```

`/etc/anaconda3/lib/` is not on my `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, per the documentations of [dlopen](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html), this should not be found. If I'm not allowed to modify the content in `/etc/anaconda3/lib/`, is there away to set higher priority to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and have `ctypes` finding my customized build of `openblas`?

Comment: `ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('/home/username/.local/lib/libopenblas.so.0').name`?

Comment: Did you check your environment variables from *Anaconda* prompt (or from which ever terminal you launch *Python*)?

Comment: that can be found too. My real question is that when loading my own `.so` lib which links to `libopenblas.so.0`, the anaconda version `openblas` is used, because it seems to be preferred by `ctypes`.

Comment: You mean `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`? No it doesn't include anaconda lib in the anaconda prompt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that python is compiled with `RPATH` pointing to `$ORIGIN/../../lib`, which always has higher precedence than `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. To override this, I compile the library with `-Wl,-rpath,--enable-new-dtags` flags to set an empty `RUNPATH` which will replace `RPATH` but with lower precedence than `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. This fixed my problem and allows my library to link to `libopenblas.so.0` outside the anaconda lib.